# JSON Jquery parse

Tags: jquery, json

I've been stuck trying to parse this out. I've tried google and it doesn't seem to work...

Here's the JSON:

```
{
"1": [
    {
        "SUBCATEGORY_ID": "1",
        "CATEGORY_ID": "1",
        "NAME": "Sonic",
        "SORTS": "1" 
    } 
],
"2": [
    {
        "SUBCATEGORY_ID": "2",
        "CATEGORY_ID": "2",
        "NAME": "Captain Planet",
        "SORTS": "1" 
    },
    {
        "SUBCATEGORY_ID": "3",
        "CATEGORY_ID": "2",
        "NAME": "Rocco Mordern life",
        "SORTS": "2" 
    },
    {
        "SUBCATEGORY_ID": "4",
        "CATEGORY_ID": "2",
        "NAME": "Sponge BOB",
        "SORTS": "3" 
    } 
]
```

}

This is my jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'subcategoriesAjax.php',
        success: function(data){
                //alert(data.1[0]);
        }
    }); 
}); // $(document).ready(function(){
```

It doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried `data.1.0` & `data.1[0].SORTS`.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `data["1"][0].SORTS`? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data["1"][0]
```

should do the trick

Comment: You don't even need the double quotes

Comment: technically true, only done here for readability, to distinguish between using the `[]` operators for array access and object access.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the dot notation to access properties when they are numbers. Use the array-like notation instead:

```
data['1'][0]
```

Even better would be to use something other than a number as the key, or to use a normal array.

Answer (score 0):

try:

...

success: function(data){
alert(data.d);
}

...

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(data["1"][0]["SUBCATEGORY_ID"]);
```

Result of this alert is 1.

Comment: It didn't work but thank you. alert(data["1"][0].SUBCATEGORY_ID); This worked though.

Comment: I tried my solution and it worked for me. I'm glad you solved your problem. Cheers :)